# Prisma: Warning when adding a member to a company using prisma nested queries

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I'm encountering an error while trying to add a member to a company using Prisma in TypeScript. Below is the code snippet of the function I'm using:

```
async addMember(id: string, addMemberDto: AddMemberDto) {
    const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: addMemberDto.userId,
      },
    });

    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
    }

    const company = await this.prisma.company.findUnique({
      where: {
        id,
      },
    });

    if (!company) {
      throw new NotFoundException('Company not found');
    }

    const isMember = await this.prisma.companyMember.findFirst({
      where: {
        companyId: company.id,
        userId: addMemberDto.userId,
      },
    });

    if (isMember) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException('User is already a member');
    }

    const companyMember = await this.prisma.company.update({
      where: {
        id: company.id,
      },
      data: {
        companyMembers: {
          create: {
            userId: addMemberDto.userId,
            role: addMemberDto.role,
          },
        },
      },
    });

    return companyMember;
}
```

However, I'm receiving the following warning:
Argument type {data: {companyMembers: {create: {role: CompanyRole | undefined, userId: string}}}, where: {id: string}} is not assignable to parameter type SelectSubset<CompanyUpdateArgs<$Extensions.DefaultArgs>, CompanyUpdateArgs<$Extensions.DefaultArgs>>

My database schema is as follows:

```
...

model User {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  email          String @unique
  hashedPassword String

  firstName String?
  lastName  String?

  role UserRole @default(USER)

  project       Project[]
  projectMember ProjectMember[]

  company       Company[]
  companyMember CompanyMember[]
}

model Project {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  name        String
  description String?

  owner   User   @relation(fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
  ownerId String

  projectMembers ProjectMember[]

  company   Company @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id])
  companyId String
}

model ProjectMember {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  role ProjectRole @default(MEMBER)

  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String

  project   Project @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id])
  projectId String
}

model Company {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  name        String
  description String?

  owner   User   @relation(fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
  ownerId String

  companyMembers CompanyMember[]
  project        Project[]
}

model CompanyMember {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  role CompanyRole @default(MEMBER)

  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String

  company   Company @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id])
  companyId String
}

enum ProjectRole {
  OWNER
  ADMIN
  MEMBER
}

enum UserRole {
  ADMIN
  USER
}

enum CompanyRole {
  OWNER
  ADMIN
  MEMBER
}
```

While the code works as expected, these warnings suggest that there might be an issue with the way I'm structuring the Prisma update query. I'm looking to resolve these warnings to ensure cleaner and more robust code. Any insights or suggestions on how to address these warnings would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

In attempting to resolve the warning, I tried creating a separate entity called ProjectMember and establishing a connection between Company and ProjectMember to handle the association between users and projects within a company. However, even after implementing this change, I still encountered the warning mentioned earlier.
I also explored various posts on Stack Overflow where individuals suggested similar approaches to what I have implemented. Furthermore, I consulted the Prisma documentation to ensure alignment with recommended practices.